# does iOS device simulator use actual device properties

Tags: ios-simulator

I was wondering if the iOS Simulator can some how actually simulate the processor speeds of the iPhone 5, iPad 4(retina) and iPad 3 found at this link:http://browser.primatelabs.com/ios-benchmarks

For example if I run an app I create in xcode on the iPad 3 will it run twice as fast on the iPad 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The iOS simulator doesn't even use the same architecture (it's compiled for the Intel chipset as opposed to ARM), hence you can't (at least in the current incarnation) do this.

On a similar basis, the performance information within Instruments is only meaningful when run on a device.

Answer (score 0):

no, it only simulates on the OS, it actually did not check the limitation of processor and RAM